# Implementing a search with paging using ajax php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, search

Hey folks I am trying to implement a search functionality in  a website using ajax,php,mysql,jquery.Now my application works fine when I go to a list page(**Page with list of items on the site**).But I have a search on the index page whose results have to be displayed on the list page.Basic pagination is done using php and works for the links coming from menu,but **fails for search.**(i.e if redirected from the index page using a search query it does not work)

The search text box:

```
        <form name="homePageSearchForm" method="post" action="cities.php" autocomplete="off">
                 <!--   <input type="hidden" value="e.g kolte patil life republic, wagholi pune" id="hiddenExData" name="hiddenExData">-->
                    <div style="padding-top:5px; line-height:20px; width:280px;" class="flt">
                    <div class="flt"><strong>Locality, City, Builder or Project name</strong><span style="color:#FF3300;">*</span><br>
                    <div class="flt"><input type="text" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='e.g kolte patil life republic, wagholi pune';" onFocus="if(this.value=='e.g kolte patil life republic, wagholi pune') this.value='';" value="e.g kolte patil life republic, wagholi pune" name="SearchValue" id="searchId" title="Search" class="headerinput ac_input" autocomplete="off">
```

**List** page div where content has to be displayed.

```
            <div class="flt width710" id="displayProp">
            <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="flt mapnewalert"> <?php //echo ucfirst($_SESSION['$city']) ?></div>
            <div style="float:right" id="toppagesel">
            <?php 
                    echo $pages->display_pages();
                    echo $pages->display_items_per_page();
                /*  if(isset($localitySearch) && $localitySearch!='' && isset($citySearch) && $citySearch!='')
                    {
                        $query = "SELECT * from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join locality on properties.locality_id=locality.locality_id where (cities.city_name like '%".$citySearch."%' and locality.locality_name like '%".$localitySearch."%') and (property_price_min between '78 Lacs' and '80 Lacs') $pages->limit";
                    }*/

                //  else
                //  {
                    $query = "SELECT * from properties,locality,cities where properties.city_id='".$_SESSION['$cityId']."' and properties.locality_id=locality.locality_id and properties.city_id=cities.city_id $pages->limit";
                //  }

                //  echo $query;
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    //$getProperty =    $propertyDetails->getPropertyDetailsByCityIdPaginate($_SESSION['$cityId'],$limit);
            ?>
            <?php //echo $pages->display_pages(); ?><?php //echo $pages->display_items_per_page();?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now on clicking the search button I call a javascript function as follows

```
                   <input type="submit" onClick="**handleHomePageSearch(0,'e')**;return false;" value="SEARCH" class="hpnewsubmitbtn">
```

The js function:

```
             function handleHomePageSearch(buttonEle,e) {
             var criteria  = document.getElementById("searchCriteria").value;
            var searchVal = document.getElementById("searchId").value;
            xmlHttpSearchct=GetXmlHttpObject();
            var cur_page = document.getElementById("current_page").innerHTML;

            var url="fetchCity.php?&searchVal="+searchVal+"&buttonEle="+buttonEle+"&cur_page="+cur_page;
            alert(url);
            xmlHttpSearchct.open("GET",url,false);

            xmlHttpSearchct.send(null);

                           var Searchres=xmlHttpSearchct.responseText;
                       **//To get the response**
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                                    document.getElementById('displayProp').innerHTML=Searchres;
                }
          }
```

**This gives the response back in the form of HTML but i am not able to display it on the list(properties.php) page.Also the pagination does not work if I go using the search values.**

The **fetchCity.php** contans the query for the search and the HTML to return with data.

```
                   $searchValue= $_GET['searchVal'];
$buttonEle  = $_GET['buttonEle'];
$current_page=$_GET['cur_page'];

    $locCity = explode(" ",$searchValue);
    $localitySearch =   $locCity[0];
    $citySearch     =    $locCity[1];

        $query = "SELECT * from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join locality on properties.locality_id=locality.locality_id where (cities.city_name like '%".$citySearch."%' and locality.locality_name like '%".$localitySearch."%') and (property_price_min between '78 Lacs' and '80 Lacs') $pages->limit";
    //echo $query;
    exit;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


?>


<div class="width710" id="displayProp">

     <?php 


/*print_r($getProperty);
foreach($result as $property)*/
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
      ?>
            <div class="projectlisttiger">      
            <div class="proptigerhead">PropTiger Recommends</div>   
                <div class="spacer5">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="listnewimg flt">
                    <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php">
                        <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo ($row['property_cover_image']) ?>" width="186" height="125" border="0">
                        <img src="admin/uploads/Cilantra1/1cilantra-large.jpg" width="186" height="125" border="0">
                    </a>
                     <div class="newlistlaunch"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><img width="65" height="65" border="0" src="images/projects/kolte-patil/cilantra/new_launch_blue.png"></a>
                     </div>                             
                </div>

                <div class="listright">
                    <div style="width:498px; height:42px;" class="flt">
                        <div class="list-logo flt">
                            <div class="buildborder"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><img width="80" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Kolte Patil" src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $row['builder_logo']?>"></a>
                            </div>
                               <div class="tablistname"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><?php echo $row['property_name'] ?></a></div>
                        </div>   
                        <?php if ($row['property_price_min']!=0) { ?>      
                        <div class="listprice">
                            <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif"> <?php echo $row['property_price_min'] ?> Lacs - <?php echo $row['property_price_max'] ?> Lacs       
                        </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="listprice">
                             <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif">Price on Request
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </div>

                        <div class="spacer3">&nbsp;</div>        SPACER

                    <div class="listbox">
                        <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><strong>Address</strong>:<?php echo $row['locality_name'] ?>, <?php echo $row['city_name'] ?><br> <strong>Types</strong>: 2BHK &amp; 3BHK
                        <br><strong>Sizes:</strong> <?php echo $row['property_size_min'] ?> sqft - <?php echo $row['property_size_max'] ?> sqft </a>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-left:-3px;" class="flt">
                        <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><input type="button" value="View Details" class="detail_project"></a>
                        </div>     
                      <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><input type="button" onClick="showEnqForm('2659','Cilantro'); return false;" value="Enquire Now" class="enquire_project"></div>
                    </div>
                           <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>        SPACER                                
                </div>
                <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>                  SPACER
       </div>              

   <?php } 
   exit;

  // echo "<p class=\"paginate\">Page: $pages->current_page of $pages->num_pages</p>\n";
   ?>                         

        <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>
       </div>
```

I would like to know is my approach right??How can I display the search results on the other page with pagination working.

**For reference I will add the link of a reference site with similar functionality.**

Here it is: http://www.proptiger.com/
Any kind of suggestions or help would be appreciated.

pagination class:

```
         class Paginator{
var $items_per_page;
var $items_total;
var $current_page;
var $num_pages;
var $mid_range;
var $low;
var $limit;
var $return;
var $default_ipp;
var $querystring;
var $ipp_array;

function Paginator()
{
    $this->current_page = 1;
    $this->mid_range = 2;
    $this->ipp_array = array(2,4,6,8,10,'All');
    $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
}

function paginate()
{
    if(!isset($this->default_ipp)) $this->default_ipp='10';
    if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
    {
        $this->num_pages = 1;
          //$this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
    }
    $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
    $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
    $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
    if($_GET)
    {
        $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        foreach($args as $arg)
        {
            $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
            if($keyval[0] != "page" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg;
        }
    }

    if($_POST)
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
        {
            if($key != "page" And $key != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&$key=$val";
        }
    }
    if($this->num_pages > 4)
    {
        $this->return = ($this->current_page > 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">&laquo; Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</span> ";

        $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
        $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

        if($this->start_range <= 0)
        {
            $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
            $this->start_range = 1;
        }
        if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
        {
            $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
            $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
        }
        $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
            if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
            }
            if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
        }
        $this->return .= (($this->current_page < $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All') And $this->current_page > 0) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">Next &raquo;</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&raquo; Next</span>\n";
        $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
        }
        $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    $this->low = ($this->current_page <= 0) ? 0:($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
    if($this->current_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = 0;
    $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
}
function display_items_per_page()
{
    $items = '';
    if(!isset($_GET[ipp])) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
    foreach($this->ipp_array as $ipp_opt) $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'$this->querystring';return false\">$items</select>\n";
}
function display_jump_menu()
{
    for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
    {
        $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
    }
    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring';return false\">$option</select>\n";
}
function display_pages()
{
    return $this->return;
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Tell me what is $page and where is display_pages()

Comment: Those are the pagination functions.Actually didn't add them as the code already was getting large!!I will update the question for them,pls chck now.

Comment: is the given function in my answer not working

Comment: No, tried that but same result!!

Comment: ok if you are in such a trouble then earn some reputation score and start a bounty on this question

Comment: Sorry,I am a new user and don't have any idea regarding bounty!!how would that help??

Comment: see when you will earn a rep about 60 or 70 then you can give some of your reputation to users who answer this question.BTW i am only 3 days old

Comment: ok!!!Thank you for the reputation upvotes!!You have earned a lot in short time!!Great going..keep up the good work!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.paginate').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btnPage = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btnPage.attr('href'),
            success: function (resp) {
                // replace current results with new results.
                $('#project_section').html(resp);
            },
            error: function () {
                window.location.href = btnPage.attr('href');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here $(".paginate") is the class of the `<li>` in my paginator class. I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928368/paginate-records-on-client-side-issue) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make your js funcion like this

```
function handleHomePageSearch(buttonEle, e) {
    var criteria = document.getElementById("searchCriteria").value;
    var searchVal = document.getElementById("searchId").value;
    xmlHttpSearchct = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var cur_page = document.getElementById("current_page").innerHTML;

    var url = "fetchCity.php?&searchVal=" + searchVal + "&buttonEle=" + buttonEle + "&cur_page=" + cur_page;
    alert(url);

    xmlHttpSearchct.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttpSearchct.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpSearchct.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('displayProp').innerHTML = xmlHttpSearchct.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttpSearchct.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlHttpSearchct.send(null);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question,those were silly typos and i messed with them while testing,but no result yet.i am really in trouble @Somebody.

Comment: I will try to put it in simple english.The Ajax function which i have added is what causing the problem I suppose.I want to replace the div present on the list(properties) page,with a div with search results,that I have in fetchCity.php. Same Div but just the content would change based on search.So I am gettng the response in firebug of the search query i have in fetchCity,but I am not able to replace the div with search results with the one on the list page.Hope I am clear enough!!Tried it doing like this `document.getElementById('displayProp').innerHTML=Searchres;
` but I get a blank div.